# AngularJS Inserting child state parameter into $urlRouterProvider (UI-Router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use `$urlRouterProvider` to redirect me from a parent state to a child one, though the child one is a URL that accepts a parameter. (child url: `/:page?pageId`).

I am simply hoping to enter the application by entering from `www.example.com/home`, where the `$urlRouterProvider` should then take over the routing.

The code looks something like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/home', '/home/?pageId=1');
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'home.tpl.html'
}).state('home.page', {
    url: '/:page?pageId',
    templateUrl: '...'
});
```

As you can see, I was hoping that by using the `$urlRouterProvider` I would be able to direct the location from the `/home` *(parent state)* to the parameterized child state `/:page?pageId` by forcing the url `/?pageId=1`. Instead, it just appends a trailing slash to `/home/`.

Here is a very dysfunctional plnkr of this madness: http://plnkr.co/edit/XZ4jkhqzQmykIgx0CvH2?p=preview

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IwyQ9AIdDopDneOvUgN5?p=preview)

I am not sure why the above notation is not working *(if intended to skip it or not)*, but with this adjustment it will work:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', { 
    url: '/home',
    abstract: true, 
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'controller',
}).state('home.child', {
    url: '/:page?pageId',
    templateUrl: 'childtemplate.html',
    params : {                 // HERE we do define the defaults
      pageId: {value: 1},      // these would serve as a starting value
    }
});
```

So, what we are effectively doing here, is to declaring the default value out of url, but in the `params: {}` setting:

```
...
params : {
    pageId: {value: 1},
}
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IwyQ9AIdDopDneOvUgN5?p=preview)